# Flag lists alternative

Tags: 6

Is there any good way to let users create custom node lists? I'm using Drupal 6.

I've found the [Flag Lists](http://drupal.org/project/flag_lists) module, but it has not been fully released, yet.

Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you need multiple lists per user that differ by user? The  http://drupal.org/project/flag module itself is stable and provides the functionality if you have standard lists/flags on a sitewide basis.

Comment: yeah i know about it but i need to let users create lists on their own ;)

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue is another alternative

Comment: it's allmost what i was looking for. the problem is that user can have just one queue and i need to make him able to have unlimited queues/lists

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the [Node Queue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module with the [Smartqueue Per User](http://drupal.org/project/smartqueue_users).

Although it's not listed on the front page, you can now get the [6.x-2.x-dev](http://drupal.org/node/256943/release) version which does the multiple lists (or queues) per user.

I've also got a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1188276) to make it work with the latest version of Node Queue.

This module might appear flaky because few sites use it and the issue queue is stale, but it really does work the way it's supposed to. We're using that 6.x-2.x-dev on a production site with premium content and it gives us NO problems whatsoever.